# Shelve Module Not Working

Tags: python

After I reinstalled Python to move it from an AppData folder to Program Files, it looks like the shelve module is no longer working and I receive the error below when I call upon `shelve.open()`.

Please help!

```
 >>> import shelve
    >>> myShelf = shelve.open('data')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\dbm\dumb.py", line 81, in _create
        f = _io.open(self._datfile, 'r', encoding="Latin-1")
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data.dat'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
        myShelf = shelve.open('data')
      File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\shelve.py", line 243, in open
        return DbfilenameShelf(filename, flag, protocol, writeback)
      File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\shelve.py", line 227, in __init__
        Shelf.__init__(self, dbm.open(filename, flag), protocol, writeback)
      File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\dbm\__init__.py", line 94, in open
        return mod.open(file, flag, mode)
      File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\dbm\dumb.py", line 303, in open
        return _Database(file, mode, flag=flag)
      File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\dbm\dumb.py", line 69, in __init__
        self._create(flag)
      File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\dbm\dumb.py", line 83, in _create
        with _io.open(self._datfile, 'w', encoding="Latin-1") as f:
    PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'data.dat'
    >>>
```

Comment: "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data.dat'". The shelve module is working fine, you just need to make sure the file you want to read is there.

Comment: Try running the python with sudo; suggesting because of Permission denied in your error.

Comment: Evert - shelve.open is supposed to create the file if it's not there.

Comment: psuedoAJ - not sure what running with sudo means, could you please elaborate?

Comment: I think, @psuedoAJ means the administrator right under Linux system.  If you use Windows please check whether your account has Administrator right,which allows you to create and write file.

Answer (score 0):

The error "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data.dat'" shows you, it can not find the data.dat, please check the file location.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem using Windows 10. I solved the issue by changing the working directory to a folder under my profile.

```
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\Nat\\Documents\\Python\\Project 1')
```

I presume I didn't have permission to write a file 'Program Files'.